# How to output one value while the function returns two value in python？

Tags: python, matlab, function, arguments, return-value

In python, for example, a function returns two values,

```
def f():
    return 1, 2
```

while in some occasions I care about one of output values. In matlab, I can simply do

```
[out1, ~] = f()
```

But in python, how can I do. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @dano, would you put that in an answer so vincent can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty similar in Python:

```
out, _ = f()
```

Note that this will only work with exactly two values. If you have more, you have to add an `_`, for each, unless you're using Python 3.x, which allows you to do this:

```
>>> x, *_ = [1,3,4,5]
>>> print _
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

A typical pattern might be something like

```
out, _ = f()
```

This does actually end up declaring a variable called `_`, though it shouldn't really matter.

Or you could do this:

```
out = f()[0]
```